# How to optimize this query with large data

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

```
select ticket_type,f_rows.remaining_uses,t.source,count(t.id) as total
FROM (
    -- Filter rows to get those where remaining_uses > 0 and status = 1 
    SELECT * FROM (
        --Get all the latest rows for each ticket
        SELECT ticket_id,final_remaining_uses AS remaining_uses,final_status AS status,action_when 
        FROM TicketHistory th
        INNER JOIN (SELECT max(th.id) AS id FROM TicketHistory GROUP BY ticket_id) maxid ON th.id = maxid.id 
    ) latest_rows
    WHERE remaining_uses > 0 AND status = 1 --and (action_when < current_date and action_when > current_date -30)
) f_rows 
INNER JOIN Ticket t ON f_rows.ticket_id = t.id
WHERE t.expiry_date >= current_date -1 and source in (0,1,2,6,7,8) and (created_date < current_date and created_date > current_date - 30)


GROUP BY ticket_type, f_rows.remaining_uses, t.source
order by source, ticket_type, remaining_uses;
```

What I'm doing here is getting the latest rows for each ticket from history table.
then filtering rows for tickets which are not active and there is not usage left on that ticket.
then filtering the data with expiry date and other checks

Is there is a way to optimize this query? currently this query take a very long time and postgresql crashes before it returns any data.

both ticket and ticket history has more than 11M rows each.

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE ticket
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  source integer NOT NULL,
  status integer NOT NULL,
  ticket_type integer NOT NULL,
  remaining_uses integer NOT NULL,
  expiry_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  price numeric(20,2) NOT NULL,
  created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  pax_type integer NOT NULL,
  last_updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  service integer,
  client_id character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT skybus_ticket_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT skybus_ticket_sale_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sale_id)
      REFERENCES skybus_sale (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE ticket
  OWNER TO umd;

-- Index: ticket_client_id_idx

-- DROP INDEX ticket_client_id_idx;

CREATE INDEX ticket_client_id_idx
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (client_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

-- Index: ticket_profile_id_idx

-- DROP INDEX ticket_profile_id_idx;

CREATE INDEX ticket_profile_id_idx
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (profile_id);

-- Index: ticket_sale_id

-- DROP INDEX ticket_sale_id;

CREATE INDEX skybus_ticket_sale_id
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (sale_id);

-- Index: ticket_ticket_number

-- DROP INDEX ticket_ticket_number;

CREATE INDEX ticket_ticket_number
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (ticket_number COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

-- Index: ticket_ticket_number_like

-- DROP INDEX ticket_ticket_number_like;

CREATE INDEX ticket_ticket_number_like
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (ticket_number COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops);

-- Index: ticket_topup_for_idx

-- DROP INDEX ticket_topup_for_idx;

CREATE INDEX ticket_topup_for_idx
  ON ticket
  USING btree
  (topup_for COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

--===============================

```
CREATE TABLE tickethistory
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  ticket_id integer,
  action integer NOT NULL,
  action_result integer NOT NULL,
  initial_status integer NOT NULL,
  final_status integer NOT NULL,
  final_remaining_uses integer NOT NULL,
  ticket_type integer NOT NULL,
  action_when timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  last_updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  service integer,
  CONSTRAINT tickethistory_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT tickethistory_ticket_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id)
      REFERENCES ticket (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tickethistory
  OWNER TO umd;

-- Index: tickethistory_ticket_id

-- DROP INDEX tickethistory_ticket_id;

CREATE INDEX tickethistory_ticket_id
  ON tickethistory
  USING btree
  (ticket_id);
```

--===== Execution plan -- this is with row_number() change

```
    "HashAggregate  (cost=4526158.63..4526158.64 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=382849.323..382849.376 rows=41 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3880592.94..4526158.62 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=380338.613..382825.688 rows=11745 loops=1)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on sub  (cost=3880592.94..4463424.47 rows=6563 width=8) (actual time=126346.043..258837.523 rows=293717 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((sub.remaining_uses > 0) AND (sub.rn = 1) AND (sub.status = 1))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 15244064"
"              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=3880592.94..4191436.42 rows=15542174 width=203) (actual time=126345.775..237172.180 rows=15537781 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=3880592.94..3919448.38 rows=15542174 width=203) (actual time=126345.757..180461.191 rows=15537781 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: th.ticket_id, th.*"
"                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3050616kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on skybus_tickethistory th  (cost=0.00..483544.74 rows=15542174 width=203) (actual time=14.091..53312.782 rows=15537781 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using skybus_ticket_pkey on skybus_ticket t  (cost=0.00..9.55 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.418..0.418 rows=0 loops=293717)"
"              Index Cond: (id = sub.ticket_id)"
"              Filter: ((source = ANY ('{0,1,2,6,7,8}'::integer[])) AND (created_date < ('now'::cstring)::date) AND (expiry_date >= (('now'::cstring)::date - 1)) AND (created_date > (('now'::cstring)::date - 30)) AND (ticket_type = ANY ('{2,3,4,5,6,7,16,17, (...)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Total runtime: 383045.381 ms"
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I edited the quesiton

Comment: That's not the execution plan for your query - the execution plan has a `WindowAgg` step, but your query has no window functions. The plan for the original query might be more helpful (and maybe the one for the `distinct on()` solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct on ()` is typically the fastest way of solving [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problems in Postgres:

```
select ticket_type,f_rows.remaining_uses,t.source,count(t.id) as total
FROM (
    -- Filter rows to get those where remaining_uses > 0 and status = 1 
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        --Get all the latest rows for each ticket
        SELECT distinct on (ticket_id) 
               ticket_id, 
               final_remaining_uses AS remaining_uses, 
               final_status AS status, action_when 
        FROM TicketHistory th
        order by ticket_id, id desc
    ) latest_rows
    WHERE remaining_uses > 0 
      AND status = 1 --and (action_when  current_date -30)
) f_rows 
  JOIN Ticket t ON f_rows.ticket_id = t.id
WHERE t.expiry_date >= current_date -1 
  and source in (0,1,2,6,7,8) 
  and created_date  current_date - 30
GROUP BY ticket_type, f_rows.remaining_uses, t.source
order by source, ticket_type, remaining_uses;
```

`distinct on()` together with the `order by` returns the row with the highest value of `tickethistory.id` for each `ticket_id`.

An index on `tickethistory (ticket_id, id desc)` would probably help. Maybe even one on `tickethistory (ticket_id, id desc, final_remaining_uses, final_status, action_when)` to enable an index only scan.

However, a timestamp column that stores the moment of creation might be more accurate. If `tickethistory.id` is e.g. generated id through sequence (because it's a `serial`) then those values might not reflect that actual order of insertion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `row_number()` to get the latest row for each ticket in a single pass:

```
with    last_history as
        (
        select  *
        from    (
                select  row_number() over (partition by ticket_id
                                           order by th desc) rn
                ,       *
                from    TicketHistory
                ) sub
        where   rn = 1 -- Latest history row only
        )
select  *
from    ticket t
join    th
on      t.id = th.ticket_id
where   remaining_uses > 0
        and <... other conditions ...>
```

Comment: this certainly improve the query time. so do i need to use distinct or this approach?

i was under the impression that the way I'm doing is more quicker

Comment: I'd go with a_horse_with_no_name's answer, that's more readable than the `row_number()` :)